# Java Class Long - method longValue()

Tags: java, long-integer

Why has the java class Long a method longValue()? And what is the use of that? The java doc says

```
the numeric value represented by this object after conversion to type long.
```

Is there a case where I need this? Could the following first code code differ from the second for any long value?

```
//Is there a value where this myLong value contains other...
Long l = new Long("...");
long myLong = l;

//...than this one?
Long l = new Long("...");
long myLong = l.longValue();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before Java5 there is No [`Autoboxing and Unboxing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) so that `longValue()`  method casts to primitive long and returns.

```
public long More ...longValue() {
722         return (long)value;
723     }
```

So there is no specific difference.  Any way after java5  the below code is enough

```
Long l = new Long("...");
long myLong = l;
```

Answer (score 3):

Long extends Number which has an `abstract long longValue()` method. So `Long` must implement it, the same way it implements `doubleValue` for example.

When you have a `Long aLong` you can always write `long primitive = aLong;` and use auto-boxing, so the method is not very useful in the `Long` class.

Answer (score 2):

It's a old method, introduced in the first version of Java.
Back in the day, there were no outbox/autoboxing features in the language (they were only introduced in Java 5.0), and this was the only way to get a `long` from a `Long`.