# Why does java.lang.Long's .longValue() cast its (long) instance value to long?

Tags: java, numbers, long-integer

I have been investigating the `java.lang.Long` class source code.

Consider this:

```
public final class Long extends Number implements Comparable<Long> {
      ....
      private final long value;    
      ....
      public long longValue() {
            return (long)value;
      }
      ....
}
```

What is the reason to cast `long` to `long`?

Why not <s>reralize</s> serialize (?) it into Number class in this case?

**P.S.1** [source code link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.longValue%28%29)

I have these possible explanations:

1. Carelessness of developers
2. Compliance with some unified code style
3. It was made for some special case, but I don't understand why.

**P.S.2**

my java version - `1.7.0_45-b18`

**P.S.3**
just for information:

`Integer`:

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer> {
          ....
          private final int value;    
          ....
          public int intValue() {
            return value;
          }    
          ....
}
```

`Short`:

```
public final class Short extends Number implements Comparable<Short> {
            ....
            private final short value;    
            ....
            public short shortValue() {
                return value;
            }
            ....
}
```

and same for `Byte` and `Character`. (None of these cast like-to-like.)

Is it a problem, or may it just be forgotten?

Comment: +1 for noting it! A good question

Comment: Looks like its there just for symmetry reasons with the other methods? Maybe even just a simple copy&paste error?

Comment: +1! goes to favourites :)

Comment: I agree with @sanbhat, this is probably the result of a copy/paste. Link to the source?

Comment: @kocko: GNU classpath isn't the only implementation of the Java standard library.

Comment: @kocko: Please have a look at the Oracle JDK's source.

Comment: There's no actual answer to this other than that's what the guy wrote.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922867/java-class-long-method-longvalue

Comment: @slugmandrew I am not sure

Comment: The programmer was bragging.

Comment: the extended class `Number` is used in generics, all of numerical objective classes(Float, Short, Integer,...) are extended from Number

Comment: as it relates to current business?

Comment: I would guess that they changed the implementation of the Number classes several times, and the implementer got tired of adding and removing casts.

Answer (score 4):

I have assumption that it was made that code was unified for related methods?

observe a single code style.

```
 public short shortValue() {
        return (short)value;
    }


    public int intValue() {
        return (int)value;
    }


    public long longValue() {
        return (long)value;
    }


    public float floatValue() {
        return (float)value;
    }


    public double doubleValue() {
        return (double)value;
    }
```

But I noticed that in java 1.6(1.6_0_45 at least) for `Integer` class

```
public int intValue() {
            return (int)value;
}
```

but in java 1.7 for `Integer` class

```
public int intValue() {
            return value;
}
```

**Conclusion**: developers have not paid attention to this aspect.

**P.S.**
It is my assumption only.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java?av=f   above is the link to java 6 openjdk code. The java 6 integer class does not have (int)value casting.

Comment: mmm.... seems java 1.6 have different realization at different versions. Right now I saw it on PC of my colleague